# Determine the expectation E(XY) of Joint PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am practising some exam questions and am failing to understand the problem at hand. I believe I am supposed to take the double integral of the joint PDF that can be calculated by noting that $f_X,_Y(x,y) = f_{X|Y}(x)*f_Y(y)$.

The problem is as such:

The conditional pdf for X given Y = y, is

$
  f_{X|Y=y}(x) =
\begin{cases}
1/y^2,  & \text{for 0 $\leq$ x $\leq$ $y^2$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}
$

While the marginal density of Y is

$
  f_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
4y^3,  & \text{for 0 $\leq$ y $\leq$ 1} \\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$

Now I think that X and Y are not independent, this is because looking at the limits of $f_{X|Y}(x)$ it is clear that if y = 0 then x must be 0. Hence, I need to double integrate over the joint pdf to find E(XY), I assume. The problem is how do I determine the limits of my integral?

Thanks for your patience, help and time! It is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limits of the integral are in fact given to you.   They are: $0\leq y\leq 1$ and $0\leq x\leq y^2$.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(XY)
& = \int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=0}^{y^2} x\,y\; f_Y(y)\;f_{X\mid Y=y}(x)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y
\\[1ex]
& = \int_{y=0}^1 y\cdot 4y^3/y^2 \int_{x=0}^{y^2} x\operatorname d x\operatorname d y
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks Graham, may I ask why we need take the integral of $xy*f_{X|Y}(x)*f_Y(y)$ ? More specifically the $xy$. Thanks again.

Comment: @Orwellian By definition of expectation: $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(g(X,Y)) & = \iint_{\mathcal {Y\times X}} g(x,y)\; f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d x \operatorname d y \\[1ex] & = \iint_{\mathcal {Y\times X}} g(x,y)\; f_{X\mid Y=y}(x)\;f_Y(y)\operatorname d x \operatorname d y \end{align}$$

Comment: @Orwellian As $\int x\operatorname d x = \frac 1 2 x^2 +\text{constant}$ then $$\begin{align}\int _0^{y^2} x \operatorname d x & = \frac {(y^2)^2}2-\frac{0^2}{2} \\[1ex] & = \tfrac 1 2 y^4\end{align}$$

Comment: Once again thanks, @Graham! I have a complete solution now but to ensure I fully understand, if I were to find the marginal distribution of X for instance I would simply be doing the following:

$\int_{0}^{1} 4y dy$ 

where 4y is the joint pdf here. Have I got the right idea and limits for this?

Comment: @Orwellian The marginal distribution of $x$ is the integral of the joint distribution with respect to $y\in[\sqrt x; 1]$.  $$\begin{align} f_X(x) & = \int_{\sqrt{x\;}}^1 f_Y(y)\,f_{X\mid Y=y}(x) \operatorname d y \\[1ex] & = \int_{\sqrt{x\;}}^1 4 y^3\,/y^2 \operatorname d y \\[1ex] & = 4 \int_{\sqrt{x\;}}^1 y \operatorname d y \\[1ex] & = 2 -2 x \end{align}$$

Comment: It seems to see how you determined the limits, please may you elaborate as to why we integrate from $\sqrt{x}$ to $1$?

Comment: @orwellian Because if $0\leq x\leq y^2$, and $0\leq y\leq 1$, then $\surd x\leq y\leq 1$

Comment: Ah ok, well I should probably have realised that. last question, I really do appreciate your time! If I were to need the mean of the marginal density of X then how do I determine the range I integrate over i.e. what's the limits for the marginal distribution?

Comment: @Orwellian No problem. Again,  since $0\leq y^2\leq 1^2$ then $0\leq x\leq 1$ so it is : $$\mathsf E(X) = \int_0^1 x f_X(x)\operatorname d x = \tfrac 1 3$$